# BOT Framework Directline API call with header attributes

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I would like to call my BOT framework Directline API with additional header attributes along with the direct line secret. How to extract that in my BOT framework code and put it in the IBOTStore for the future usage. I am wondering if I could read the header attribute in the intent level?

**Here is my sample code to parse the alexa API request:**

```
 var directLineSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["directlinesecret"];
        _client = new DirectlineClient(directLineSecret, "alexa" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", ""));

var client = new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri("https://directline.botframework.com")
        };

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("BotConnector", _secret);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ETag", "*");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("channel", _from);

        var response =
            await client.GetAsync("/api/tokens/", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        response =
            await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/conversations/", new object())
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var conversationInfo =
            await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JObject>()
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        _conversationId = (string)conversationInfo["conversationId"];
        var scopedToken = (string)conversationInfo["token"];

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("BotConnector", scopedToken);
```

**BOT Framework**

```
 public async Task None(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        try
        {...............}
```

Thank you for your advance support !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Fei Han stated, custom headers are stripped and do not reach the application, so this is not a good way to send information.

A good way to send custom data on an activity is through channel data. For non-Direct Line channels, there is a tutorial on how to do that [here](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/03/28/custom-channel-data/). 
Luckily for Direct Line, there is no pre-formatted schema for data on the channelData property that you need to keep your JSON in, so you can essentially form the data however you would like.

Comment: Thanku. I did it in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to call my BOT framework Directline API with additional header attributes along with the direct line secret. How to extract that in my BOT framework code and put it in the IBOTStore for the future usage.

Based on my test, the additional custom headers that we specify in Direct Line API request would be stripped, the bot application would not receive the custom headers.

If you'd like to pass some useful information and persist it in Bot data store so that you can retrieve it in LUIS dialog or other code logic within your bot application. You can try to send an `event` activity via Direct Line API, specifying the useful information in the body of the request, and then in your bot application you can extract the data from that `event` activity and store the data in `UserData` or `ConversationData` etc

Comment: Thank you for our reply. Do you have any sample to add data in the event to post it as a json to directline api and read that in BOT framework?

Comment: The directline api documentation of [sending an activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-send-activity?view=azure-bot-service-3.0).